# Disable jquery script for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to disable following script when the website is opened in mobile device, because i don't want unnecesary animations:

```
<script src="js/eskju.jquery.scrollflow.js"></script>
```

In HTML this script works with these classes:

```
<div class="scrollflow -slide-right -opacity">
//some code...
</div>
```

I'm begginer, and I have little knowledge about JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Google? https://www.google.com.au/#safe=off&q=disable+javascript+file+on+mobile

Comment: Are you only taking about mobile device or it include all devices and tab. Disabling a script for view may not be a good idea.You will again need to enable it when the view changes and if you have plan to for fluid design

Comment: Yes, i googled and found multiple solutions, but as i said, i have very limited knowledge about javascript, so I need an answer precisely for this thing. I tried solutions that others posted, and none of them worked.

Comment: I think you may need to narrow down the requirement, "mobile device" is very broad. There are portable machines that support both touch and mouse events. Screen size is an increasingly difficult feature to filter anything with as well. So the first step could be, should it be disabled for anything supporting touch or a specific screen size? Or maybe even a combination of both...

Comment: It should be disabled for all touchscreen devices, such as smartphones and tablets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to this script:

```
<script src="js/eskju.jquery.scrollflow.js" id="scScrollFlow"></script>
```

Add this javascript code at the bottom of your BODY:

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('#scScrollFlow').remove();
}
```

---

**Update:** I have tested it for you. This following solution will work fine:

First, open your file eskju.jquery.scrollflow.js, find and remove this code:

```
$( document ).ready( function()
        {
            new ScrollFlow();
        });
```

Add this javascript code to your site:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function()
{
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) == false) {
        new ScrollFlow();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer seemed the most logical for me. I did everything as you said, but no luck.

Comment: You can only use jQuery after document ready - and then the script has already been read. The other way around (actively creating the link) *might* work. Browser sniffing has been deprecated though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I registered today and I don't know to handle JsFiddle :(

Comment: I just updated the solution. See above. Logic is that we only init the ScrollFlow if the browser is not a mobile one.

Comment: Yes, it works! I don't know how to thank you. I spent three hours figuring out how to solve this. Many, many thanks! Cheers!

Comment: You could thank him by clicking on the greyed out check mark on the left of the question to accept it. ;-)